# How can response header can be modified?

Tags: node.js, request

i have a problem that break my mind since 2 days.

```
request( {url: url } , function(err,res, body){ res.headers['...'] = ...; return res }).pipe(response);
```

I thought this code change the header from the first response then put him on the second response. but NOT, all attempt fail. I try and I try but NOTHING, NOTHING WORKK.

Look, I'm really in peace and open-minded.

that's my code clear and concise :

```
   modify_header(err,res,body){

        var header = res.headers;

        header['x-frame-options'] = null;
        header['Set-Cookie'] =  'HttpOnly;';
        return res;
    }


   request_src(req,response){

      let isabsolute = this.decode_href(req.url);


      if(!isabsolute) {
           request.get({ url : this.url+req.url , headers : this.headers },this.modify_header).pipe(response);
      }else{
           request.get({ url : isabsolute , headers : this.headers },this.modify_header).pipe(response);
      }

     return false;

}
```

request_src(req,response) is a function called in http.createServer so, req & response are just the request from clients.
then, when i do `request.get( {url:this.url ...` I send client's request to an another site, like a proxy. but i need to change the header between the "other site" and the client. and believe me for sure, function modify_header modify nothing.

no, i lie just a little, when i set `header['x-frame-options'] = null;`res.headers is equals to null. that's ok
BUT, in the browser (client side) It just doesn't work that way. 'x-frame-options' is deny or something that's not mine (the same for cookie).

can you help me please, I pull out my hair since 2 days and this isn't good for me.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that *callbacks* actually happen after a request is complete, which is way after the pipe has already begun streaming data to the response. You probably want to hook into the *response event*, which would look something like this:

```
request.get({ url: this.url + req.url, headers: this.headers })
    .on('response', function (resp) {
        resp.headers['my-custom-header'] = 'blah';
    })
    .pipe(response);
```

The `response` event is emitted *before* streaming to the destination (which in this case, is back to the original caller), so you should be able to do what you want using this method.

Comment: hoo that's magic, ty man, ty soo much, you solve all my probem

Answer (score 0):

my code looks like that right now :

```
modify_header(res){

     var header = res.headers;

     header['x-frame-options'] = null;
     header['Set-Cookie'] =  'HttpOnly;';
    return res;
}


request_src(req,response){

    console.log('original: ',req.url);
    let isabsolute = this.decode_href(req.url);

    if(!isabsolute) {

        request.get({ url : this.url+req.url , headers : this.headers })
        .on('response',this.modify_header)
        .pipe(response);

    }else{

        request.get({ url : isabsolute , headers : this.headers})
        .on('response',this.modify_header)
        .pipe(response);

    }

    return false;

}
```